# Wrong IP from hostname

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox, ip-address, hostname

I have two Windows PCs connected to a network (Physical).

- Desktop - `192.168.0.100`
- Notebook - `192.168.0.101`

Both have VM VirtualBox installed, so both have the VirtualBox Host-Only Network.

- Desktop - `192.168.56.1`
- Notebook - `192.168.56.1`

But when I ping from Notebook to Desktop (using hostname), the Notebook pings to `192.168.56.1`, that is ambiguous.

Looks like when the Notebook asks for the Desktop's Adapters, it lists both `192.168.56.1` and `192.168.0.100`, so the Notebook chooses the former and pings to itself.

**The question is:**
Can I set the physical connection as default or primary? Or maybe make the virtual hidden for others in the network?

Comment: Wow... Windows should automatically respond to name resolution requests with the IP address of the interface from whence the request came, and not some other interface.

Comment: Happened to me, and I fixed it by removing the VirtualBox Host-only Network, since I only used it once

Comment: Can't do this, I use it constantly